# SqlBulkCopy giving InvalidOperationException Error that I am inserting Null Values, but all values are non-null in the table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlbulkcopy

I have a table where one of the fields is "InDatabase" (SQL Server "bit" type) which does not allow nulls.

I create a table and add a few hundred rows to it, where InDatabase is always assigned a value (InDatabase refers to whether the row is in another database)

When I call SqlBulkCopy, it is giving me an InvalidOperationException Error, with the message of:

```
"Column 'InDatabase' does not allow DBNull.Value."
```

Each Row Is Created as such:

```
ProductionDatabaseDataSet.EntriesV2Row NewRow = this.InsertTable.NewEntriesV2Row();

NewRow.MeetEntryID = MeetEntryID;
NewRow.EventID = EventID;
NewRow.MeetID = MeetID;
NewRow.AthleteID = AthleteID;
NewRow.Exhibition = Exhibition;
NewRow.Bonus = Bonus;
NewRow.EnterEvent = true;
NewRow.InDatabase = true;
if (AutoTime != null)
    NewRow.AutoTime = AutoTime ?? -1;
if (CustomTime != null)
    NewRow.CustomTime = CustomTime ?? -1;

this.InsertTable.AddEntriesV2Row(NewRow);
```

Then, after the above is called around 300 times, the SqlBulkCopy is called:

```
SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(this.Connection.ConnectionString);
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = this.Adapter.TableMappings[0].DataSetTable;
            bulkCopy.BatchSize = BatchSize;
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(InsertTable); //Throwing the error
```

I use this exact same format on about a dozen other tables with no problem.

Comment: InsertTable is?
Did this works on a single row?

Comment: No. It does not work on a single row.

Comment: i suspect ur insert query since its looks normal here

Comment: When I use a regular Insert, it works correctly. Using EntriesV2TableAdapter.Update(InsertTable) also works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it to work, but not really figured it out. I changed the bulkCopy section to this:

```
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = this.Adapter.TableMappings[0].DataSetTable;
for (int i = 0; i < this.Adapter.TableMappings[0].ColumnMappings.Count; i++)
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(
                this.Adapter.TableMappings[0].ColumnMappings[i].SourceColumn.ToString(),
                this.Adapter.TableMappings[0].ColumnMappings[i].DataSetColumn.ToString()));
bulkCopy.BatchSize = BatchSize;


bulkCopy.WriteToServer(InsertTable);
```

Not real sure why the dozen other times I did this without setting the table mappings like this worked, but for some reason, with this table, it will not work unless I do the above.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly...

I think the problem is defining `NULL` value in `c# .net`  and `SQL`. The mean of `NULL` of your programming language will not be the same in SQL.
In SQL the NULL value represnt by [System.DBNull Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx)

Just check How to [Handle Null and DBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578558%28v=bts.70%29.aspx)

Comment: But does that matter since none of the entries in that column are null?

Comment: Read the error message: There's a `null` or `DBNull` value somewhere. When you create the row, where's `Bonus` coming from? Did you read it from the database? There's a chance it's `DBNull`.

Comment: Bonus is never null. The only ones that are ever going to be null are AutoTime and CustomTime. Setting these to DBNull makes no difference as far as whether the exception is thrown. And DBNull values are accepted in the database for those values.